# How to change CapsLock key to produce "a"?

Tags: keyboard-layout, capslock

While typing I often hit the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>a</kbd> key. (QWERTZU keyboard)
This is quite annoying because the moment I realise that I hit the wrong key, I will have to delete multiple character/lines of text an rewrite them in the right form.

I am searching for a way to prevent this.

I have found a possibility to *disable* the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key in *Keyboard Layout Options*. But this would in my case mean that instead of writing an `a` I would  write nothing.

**Positive** -> I don't have to rewrite a whole line, but only one character

**Negative** -> It's not that obvious that I hit the wrong key, as a missing character is not perceivable as an upper-case line of text.

I would therefore prefer a possibility to map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>a</kbd> . Thus when hitting <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> an `a` character would be written.

**Positive** -> If I hit <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> instead of <kbd>a</kbd> I get the output I actually wanted to type.

**Negative** -> If I hit <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> in any other context I will get an `a` character. As I don't ever *intentionally* use the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key this would not really pose a problem. (I think, or does it?)

## My Question:

1. So how do I change  to <kbd>a</kbd> ?
2. And is there any case where this could be dangerous/provoke unwanted behaviour?

Comment: How did you get CapsLock and a to look all fancy and button like?

Comment: fluteflute edited my question to make them look like that, but I would be interested in that too.

Comment: You write `<kbd>a</kbd>` (it only works in questions & answers, not comments)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Specifically, I don't know how to change <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>a</kbd>, because I don't remember the keycode. I'll find it a little later. But generally speaking, you can use `xmodmap` (and `.Xmodmap`) to change your keymappings. The first time GNOME detects your `.Xmodmap` file, it'll ask if you want to always load it, and then you're set.

I also think caps lock is silly. However, the key position is useful. I like mapping it to the Control key. I use control **a lot**, and it's tiring for my pinky to be constantly reaching down in that awkward position. And as I later found, historically <kbd>Control</kbd> is where <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is currently. Anyway. Create a file in your home directory called `.Xmodmap` with the following lines:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
```

To make these changes take effect right this instant, run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

You can find keycodes on your own using `xev`. Turns out the keycode for <kbd>a</kbd> is 38, or hex 0x61. So instead your .Xmodmap could be:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = 0x61
```

I highly recommend reading through the man page, lots of interesting stuff.

Comment: Do I only need to use the last to lines you posted?   I get the following error: `xmodmap:  /home/pit/.Xmodmap:1:  bad keysym in remove modifier list 'Caps_Lock', no corresponding keycodes
xmodmap:  /home/pit/.Xmodmap:2:  bad keysym target keysym 'Caps_Lock', no corresponding keycodes
xmodmap:  2 errors encountered, aborting.`    I did not see anything in the manpage that explains this behaviour. I also tried to run the the command as sudo but it did not change the errors.

Comment: Lol, I still had the CapsLock key disabled from my previous test in Keyboard Layout Options. After re-enabling it, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: I used this guide to get caps lock to map to control, but I had to insert `add Control = Caps_Lock` in between the remove and the keysym lines to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at `man xmodmap`, it turns out there is an idempotent way to define this:

```
clear Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Caps_Lock Control_L
```

After restarting X, you should be able to run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` repeatedly without getting any "bad keysym" errors.

**Update**: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be [portable and idempotent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108207/how-to-map-caps-lock-as-the-compose-key-using-xmodmap-portably-and-idempotently).