# How do I disable the "Fn" keys on a laptop?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to disable the fn key on my laptop?

Comment: I came here because my laptop has a hardware issue and starts sending F12 keypresses randomly. Seems none of the answers here are helpful.

Answer (score 27):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will toggle between enabling/disabling Fn-key functions.

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer will work on all systems:  it does not work on my Dell.

Comment: This worked for me on Lenovo Thinkpad e450

Comment: works on dell xps

Comment: I had to use `Fn+Super+Esc` for this to work

Comment: work on my dell inspiron 7000. surprisingly simple answer, didn't expect that.

Comment: Neither works on acer

Comment: you're my hero! thx!

Answer (score 5):

Check your laptop's BIOS. Most of the BIOS handles how to change (or remove) functionality of those special keys. I have just done this in order to change the order of [Fn] and left [Ctrl] keys but I remember there is an option to cancel the [Fn] key.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar problem with [CapsLock and fixed it with xmodmap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23491/how-to-change-capslock-key-to-produce-a)

You would only have to find out the code for <kbd>fn</kbd>, perhaps you will find it in the man page of `xmodmap`.

**Update:**
Refering to [thinkwiki.com](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work#xmodmap_configuration) the `keycode` for <kbd>fn</kbd> should be `227` and the `keysym` `F35`

So the `xmodmap` syntax to disable <kbd>fn</kbd> **could** be `remove Lock = F35`
I have **not** tested it.

Answer (score 0):

On my HP laptop, in Ubuntu 20.04. I solved this issue like this,

1. At first lock your PC.
2. Press ctrl+shift+t